# Grails Ajax Help needed

Tags: grails

I am following the tutorial in Grails in Action (2nd Edition)

I'm attempting the Ajax example in Chapter 1. I could see the first quote (generated randomly). 
[image: Start page]

But after I click on the "Next Quote" button, the screen shows plaintext output instead of having the layouts.

[image: Second page]

I was following the steps in the book. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a high chance that not everybody has read that book. You have to elaborate "those" steps mentioned in the book. :)

Comment: Could you please add those steps here? or please mention it in a capsule form.

Comment: I see that url is changed, was `qotd/quote/random` and became to `qotd/quote/ajaxRandom`. I suppose, the latest link didn't planned to open by the url in the browser. So, please look and check at your `Next quote` code to fix that. I think the problem is here.
p.s. I bought that book, but didn't read it yet.

Comment: looks like the JS libraries are NOT linked in your gsp page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.. 
What seems to work is to add the following to the random.gsp header.

< script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" >< /script>

I hope this will help somebody!